# Sum of rows below in qlikview

Tags: qlikview

I have a table like this :

| Date | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 06/Jan/2021 | 300 |
| 05/Jan/2021 | 200 |
| 04/Jan/2021 | -100 |
| 03/Jan/2021 | -500 |
| 02/Jan/2021 | 200 |
| 01/Jan/2021 | 100 |

I want to get a column with the running totals but keeping the min amount to 0. The total resets to 0 once its below 0.

the expected outcome is as below

| Date | Amount | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 06/Jan/2021 | 300 | 500 |
| 05/Jan/2021 | 200 | 200 |
| 04/Jan/2021 | -100 | 0 |
| 03/Jan/2021 | -500 | 0 |
| 02/Jan/2021 | 200 | 200 |
| 01/Jan/2021 | 100 | 100 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to sort our data.

Second we need to select previous total and add current amount + add condition.

Third we need sort our table way as we like (newest on top).

Most important function used is [Peek](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/April2020/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/Scripting/InterRecordFunctions/Peek.htm).

```
// example data (I simplified data)
[data]:
LOAD 
    * 
INLINE [
    Date, Amount
    6, 300
    5, 200
    4, -100
    3, -500
    2, 200
    1, 100
];

// order as we need use data from previous row correctly
[data_ordered]:
NoConcatenate LOAD 
    *
Resident
    [data]
Order by 
    Date asc;
    
DROP Table [data];

// condition, peek function and alt needed for first row where is no data yet
[data_totals]:
LOAD
    Date,
    Amount,
    If((Amount + Alt(Peek('Total', -1), 0)) > 0,
        Amount + Alt(Peek('Total', -1), 0),
        0) as Total
Resident
    [data_ordered];
    
DROP Table [data_ordered];
```

final table:

[image: table created with Peek qlikview function]

Comment: Hi if it is ok please give a vote and select as correct answer. If you have new problem please send me link to new question. I am away on vacation but will back on Monday and will look to it. Bests Hubert

Comment: Thanks Hubert,  this one worked for me. But i have a different problem now.   i have listed below